# What does "travailler à pause" mean?

Tags: sens, travail, belgique

When I try Googling *travailler à pause* nothing relevant comes up, [Translate](https://translate.google.com/#fr/en/travailler%20%C3%A0%20pause) gives me *work to break*, which doesn't make sense to me.

It's in a list of words/expressions I have learnt for an exam. The neighboring expressions are: "travailler à horaire décalé" and "travailler comme employé".

Comment: Ah, ok. It appears to be Belgian French. I'm from France and I have no idea what it means. “*Travailler à horaire décalé*” is Belgian French too, in France we say “*travailler en horaires décalés*”.

Comment: [Travailler comme employé](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/travailler+comme+employ%C3%A9.html) refers to a person that has a working contract with a company, [employé](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/employee#English) is more or less generic. *Travailler en/à horaires décalés* refers to how working hours are organized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ce petit [lexique des belgicismes](http://didiertougard.blogspot.fr/2011/10/petit-dictionnaire-belge-les.html) donne la définition suivante du **travail à pauses** (ou *en pauses*) :

> *faire les pauses* :  travailler en équipes par roulement.

Les Français parlent de **travail posté**<sup>1</sup>. Voir l'[article de wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travail_post%C3%A9) à ce sujet

Je trouve l'emploi du mot *pause* par les Belges plutôt incongru dans ce cas et, voulant en savoir plus, je suis tombée sur ce livre : 
*[Sociologie du travail et gestion des ressources humaines](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Sociologie_du_travail_et_gestion_des_res.html?hl=fr&id=3kQV2hnr1E0C)* de Michel De Coster.

[Extrait du livre](http://books.google.fr/books?id=3kQV2hnr1E0C&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=pause%20belgicisme&source=bl&ots=cL7QqC_Iu0&sig=u95WhnXVTQcdJvfel71GlvreOws&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=32X4U5HwOuXK0QXDgoHQBQ&ved=0CFYQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=pause%20belgicisme&f=false) cité en référence ci-dessus :

« Les Belges francophones utilisent usuellement les expressions « faire les pauses » ou « tourner les pauses » pour désigner ce mode d'organisation du temps. Et, dans cet excellent instrument de travail que constitue, du reste, le *Nouveau dictionnaire des difficultés du français moderne*, le grammairien belge Joseph Hanse se trompe lorsqu'il dit : « On parle officiellement en France (...) de travail posté, c'est-à-dire assigné à un poste déterminé, et de *personnel posté* » . S'il est vrai que le belgicisme « faire les pauses » est une expression impropre puisque la pause marque précisément un arrêt dans une activité, l'expression française actuelle l'est tout autant car le poste, dérivé du langage militaire, indique bien l'assignation du travailleur à un endroit déterminé. Les sociologues français et suisses parlaient mieux autrefois, à notre avis, lorsqu'au lieu d'entretenir la confusion autour de la notion de poste, ils s'exprimaient plus clairement en usant des expression suivantes : travail par équipes successives [...] ou par roulement [...]. »

Le **travail à horaire décalé** (comme le dit Gilles en France on dit *en horaires décalés*) est une expression plus large que le travail posté. Voici la définition que donne une [brochure](http://travail-emploi.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/Le_travail_en_horaires_decales.pdf) d'une *Direction régionale des entreprises, de la concurrence, de la consommation, du travail et de l'emploi* :

« Les horaires décalés font partie des horaires dits «atypiques ». En comparaison d’une journée de travail classique (9h - 17h), les horaires se trouvent déplacés tôt le matin (se lever avant 5 heures du matin par exemple), l’après-midi ou le soir. Cela comprend aussi le travail de fin de semaine et le travail de nuit. Les horaires postés ou alternants en font partie. Les horaires décalés accompagnent aussi très souvent le travail à temps partiel. »

Il me semble qu'il faille distinguer le « travail à horaires décalés » (où les employés n'ont pas toujours le choix de l'horaire) du « travail à horaires flexibles<sup>2</sup> »  ( où l'employé peut décider dans une certaine mesure de ses horaires de travail).

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>*Shiftwork*.</sub>
<sup>2</sup>  <sub>*flexitime* or *staggered hours*.</sub>

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse, c'est très complet!